# Stopping onclick from propagating "through" other elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, popover

In [this codepen](https://codepen.io/SavanaPope/pen/abLdmbz?editors=1000), clicking on a node causes a popover to appear. Eventually, I want links and clickable things to be in the popover. Problem is, right now when you click it, the popover closes.

I'm using an onclick event so when you click anywhere (HTML body), the popover closes. I prefer this over say an "x" close button in the popover, but I don't know how to uninclude the popover in this click to close event.

```
d3.select("body").on("click", function() {
  console.log("click on body")
  tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
  tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden")
})
```

I thought maybe the d3 stopPropagation event on the "tooltip" would somehow come into play here, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way most websites handle this is by adding both a popover and a background overlay, and then only registering clicks to the background overlay.

For example:

```js
d3.select("circle")
  .on("click", clickNode);

var tooltipBg = d3
  .select(".tooltip-overlay")
  .on("click", clickBackground);
var tooltip = d3.select(".tooltip");

function clickNode(event) {
  const [x, y] = d3.pointer(event);
  
  tooltipBg.style("display", "block");
  
  tooltip
    .style("left", `${event.layerX}px`)
    .style("top", `${event.layerY}px`)
    .style("display", "block")
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .style("opacity", 1);
}

function clickBackground() {
  tooltipBg.style("display", "none");
  
  tooltip
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .on("end", () => tooltip.style("display", "none"));
}
```

```css
.tooltip-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: solid 2px red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 6px solid #eee;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<svg height="500" width="500">
  <circle r="20" cy="50" cx="50"></circle>
</svg>

<div class="tooltip-overlay"></div>
<div class="tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: thank you!! I've nearly got it working,

https://codepen.io/SavanaPope/pen/abLdmbz?editors=1000

The final aspect I can't quite figure out is the height and width of the tooltip-overlay does not seem to be respecting the 100vh/height-of-display aspect. Is there a way to make the width and height of that overlay always cover up my display space?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It would be better to ask this in a separate question, the comments are not meant for follow-up